# RSpec tests with devise: could not find valid mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I'm trying to run controller specs with devise 1.3.4. (and factory girl)
I followed the instructions in the git wiki for the project.  I am able to log in as a user using the login_user method created in the macro, but login_admin fails with the following error:

```
...
sign_in Factory.create(:admin)

Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id: 2023, email: "admin1@gmail.com", .... >
```

Factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:username) {|n| "user#{n}"}
  f.sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@gmail.com"}
  f.email_confirmation {|fac| fac.email }
  f.password "a12345Den123"
  f.password_confirmation "a12345Den123"
#  f.admin 0
end

Factory.define :admin, :class => User do |f|
  f.sequence(:username) {|n| "admin#{n}"}
  f.sequence(:email) {|n| "admin#{n}@gmail.com"}
  f.email_confirmation {|fac| fac.email }
  f.password "a12345Den123"
  f.password_confirmation "a12345Den123"
  f.admin 1
end
```

Controller macros module:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]  #it should map to user because admin is not a model of its own.  It produces the same result either way.
      @admin = Factory.create(:admin)
      sign_in @admin
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

routes

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins, :class_name => 'User'
```

One solution is to set cache_classes = false, however that isn't ideal as I use spork and don't want to have to restart it after changing a model.

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

I have something like this in my routes:

```
  devise_for :accounts, :controllers => {:confirmations => "confirmations"} do
    put "confirm_account", :to => "confirmations#confirm_account"
    get "login" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :login
    delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
    get "register" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :register
  end
```

so in my spec/support/controller_macros.rb I needed to change from:

```
  def login_account
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:account]
      @account = Factory.create(:account)
      sign_in(@account)
    end
  end
```

to

```
  def login_account
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:account]
      @account = Factory.create(:account)
      sign_in(:account, @account)
    end
  end
```

note the **sign_in(scope, resource)**

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue as the poster and changing the sign in line to sign_in :user, Factory(:admin) worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This is from the devise readme:

> Devise also ships with default routes.
>   If you need to customize them, you
>   should probably be able to do it
>   through the devise_for method. It
>   accepts several options like
>   :class_name, :path_prefix and so on,
>   including the possibility to change
>   path names for I18n

So I would check your routes file and make sure this is in there:

```
devise_for :admins, :class_name => 'User'
```

Comment: By the way it's in the README under Configuring routes.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I didn't think it was anything to do with the routes, but apparently I misunderstood.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your code for multiple `devise_for :admins` declarations in different places. This has been the cause of such an exception in my case, as it surely confuses Devise.